# Why is the scanf function evaluated first eventhough it appears lower in the list?

Tags: c

When I run this code, and I press 1 at the end of it, instead of printing out message one, it just goes straight to scanf, and only after I enter in my input does it print message one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int year;
    int decision;
    printf( "\nThis program tells the user what the GDP per capita of post-independence South Sudan was in a given year. The availability of a figure for a certain year is subject to the limitations of the data that was provided by the World Bank. " );
point_one :
    printf( "Enter a year below to get a figure for that year.\n\n" ); // message one
    scanf( "%d" , &year );
    if(2011 > year || year > 2015 )
        printf( "\nThe figure for that year is unavailable.\n" );
    else if( year == 2011 )
        printf( "\n1,516.40 USD\n" );
    else if( year == 2012 )
        printf( "\n1,179.40 USD\n" );
    else if( year == 2013 )
        printf( "\n1,779.47 USD\n" );
    else if( year == 2014 )
        printf( "\n1,322.82 USD\n" );
    else if( year == 2015 )
        printf( "\n1,119.65 USD\n" );
    printf( "\nDo you want to try again or leave?\n\n" );
    scanf ( "%d\n\n" , &decision );
    if ( decision == 1 )
        goto point_one;
    else return;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `goto` and labels instead of loops.

Comment: `scanf` returns a valuable indicator of the number of items scanned. It's worth storing and checking.

Comment: As a hint about your problem: Any white-space character in a `scanf` format string will lead to `scanf` to read and ignore any kind of white-space. But take some time to think about how it will know that it has reached the end of the white-space?

Comment: Please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) The trailing whitespace in the `scanf()` format string tells it to filter *any amount* of whitespace, but the function won't know how much that is until you actually enter a non-whitespace character. Every character in the format string has a purpose.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much! I removed the \n's at the function parameter of the last scanf. Then, I modified the point_one definition so that it'll be like this : "point_one : printf("\n");". It worked! Also, thanks to Oka for making modifying my code so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 3):

1. `void main` is invalid.
2. Do not use `goto`. There are some circumstances when using `goto` is reasonable but IMO beginners should not use it at all.
3. Check return values of scanf.
4. Use correct formats ("\n\n") was nor correct
5. In this case I would use `swich` instead of `if`s

```
int main(void) {
    int year;
    int decision;
    printf( "\nThis program tells the user what the GDP per capita of post-independence South Sudan was in a given year. The availability of a figure for a certain year is subject to the limitations of the data that was provided by the World Bank. " );
    do{
        printf( "Enter a year below to get a figure for that year.\n\n" ); // message one
        if(scanf( "%d" , &year ) != 1) {/* error handling */ exit(2);}
        switch(year)
        {
        case 2011:
            printf( "\n1,516.40 USD\n" );
            break;
        case 2012:
            printf( "\n1,179.40 USD\n" );
            break;
        case 2013:
            printf( "\n1,779.47 USD\n" );
            break;
        case 2014:
            printf( "\n1,322.82 USD\n" );
            break;
        case 2015:
            printf( "\n1,119.65 USD\n" );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "\nThe figure for that year is unavailable.\n" );
            break;
        }
        printf( "\nDo you want to try again or leave?\n\n" );
        if(scanf ( "%d" , &decision ) != 1) {/* error handling */ exit(3);}
    }while(decision == 1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/793PdYdrh

But instead of switch and ifs you can use table and make your code much better (for example it will be very easy to add more years).

```
int main(void) {
    int year;
    int decision;

    unsigned data[] = {151640, 117940, 177947, 132282, 111965};
    printf( "\nThis program tells the user what the GDP per capita of post-independence South Sudan was in a given year. The availability of a figure for a certain year is subject to the limitations of the data that was provided by the World Bank. " );
    do{
        printf( "Enter a year below to get a figure for that year.\n\n" ); // message one
        if(scanf( "%d" , &year ) != 1) {/* error handling */ exit(2);}
        if(year < 2011 || year > 2015) printf( "\nThe figure for that year is unavailable.\n" );
        else printf( "\n%d.%d USD\n", data[year - 2011] / 100, data[year - 2011] % 100);

        printf( "\nDo you want to try again or leave?\n\n" );
        if(scanf ( "%d" , &decision ) != 1) {/* error handling */ exit(3);}
    }while(decision == 1);
}
```